# %paste magic when connecting to a ipython notebook kernel

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I am using the ipython notebook to code but sometimes I like to connect to the kernel on a terminal to do some debugging. To launch the interactive terminal connected to my kernel I do:

```
ipython console --existing kernel-715d122b-4902-4c9d-a663-8da4c34c96ee.json --profile notebook
```

When I do this I do not have access to the %paste magic since it is not loaded in the notebook profile. How can I load the %paste magic in this case?

Thanks.